# Running full node over Tor

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, full-node, tor

I am attempting to run a full bitcoin-core (`v0.13.1`) node over the Tor network for the first time. I have set up my `/etc/tor/torrc` file with the following two lines:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/bitcoin_service/
HiddenServicePort 8333 127.0.0.1:8333
```

I have set up a file `~/.bitseed/bitseed.conf` with (not sure this is required)

```
onion=1
```

I retrieved my onion address from `/var/lib/tor/bitcoin-service/hostname` allowing me to set up `~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf` with settings such as:

```
onlynet=onion
onion=127.0.0.1:9050
listen=1
bind=127.0.0.1:8333
externalip=<my-onion-address>
seednode=wxvp2d4rspn7tqyu.onion
seednode=bk5ejfe56xakvtkk.onion
seednode=bpdlwholl7rnkrkw.onion
seednode=hhiv5pnxenvbf4am.onion
seednode=4iuf2zac6aq3ndrb.onion
seednode=nkf5e6b7pl4jfd4a.onion
seednode=xqzfakpeuvrobvpj.onion
seednode=tsyvzsqwa2kkf6b2.onion
banscore=10000
bantime=11
```

It seems to be working as I can see my mempool growing from the debug file, and I have **one** inbound connection. But my connection count is very small (2 or 3). Is there anything else I need to do? In particular, I wanted to confirm that I have no need to set up my firewall `ufw` to accept connections on port `8333` (or `9050`) in order to achieve inbound connections, and I have no need to redirect port 8333 or 9050 from my router to the fixed local ip address of my machine (setting up `ufw` to allow `8833` and redirecting port `8333` from router would be required if I was running a normal node).

**EDIT:** 9 connections of which one inbound, but this single inbound connection is myself. So the question really is: **How do I allow inbound connections?**

**EDIT2:** I am now of the opinion that this setting is correct. I was wrong to think a prior inbound connection was to 'myself', after 24 hours I have seen a peek of 4 inbound connections. I can confirm there is no need to tweak `ufw` or change any of your router settings (the [tor protocol](https://www.torproject.org/docs/hidden-services.html.en) is not affected by either of these), and this seems to be working having tor on top of a VPN connection (`bitmask`). Hence **I have no more questions but happy to stand corrected if any of the above is wrong**.

Comment: You can answer your own question so others see it's solved.

Comment: I d rather leave the slot open to encourage someone who really knows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your settings look correct for the versions you would have been using, I do not know about `bitseed.conf` however.

For a more up to date guide for setting up Bitcoin Core to run over Tor, you can try this [question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/70069/75001). Bitcoin Core now supports automatically configuring an ephemeral Tor service, for example.

Comment: Thx v much Will.